# How to access the content of a template within ng-template using template reference variable

Tags: angular, angular2-template, viewchild, ng-template

I want to know if it is possible to access a template component within `ng-template` using a template reference variable?
I have tried using @ViewChild and @ContentChild but none of them seems to work
Example: I want to have access to contents of app-common

```
<ng-template #first>
<app-common #second><app-common>
</ng-template>

@ViewChild('second') second1: ElementRef;
@ContentChild('second') second2: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.second1);
}

ngAfterContentInit() {
  console.log(this.second2);
}
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried with "@ContentChild" ? It should work with "@ContentChild". So maybe you did something wrong

Comment: @PierBJX I just added the ContentChild and ViewChild is tried

Comment: Did you check the DOM Tree whether the component has actually rendered or not? If it is not present in the DOM tree, then you won't be able to access it. If it is there, then u can access it.

Answer (score 0):

> The `<ng-template>` is an Angular element for rendering HTML. It is
>   never displayed directly. In fact, before rendering the view, Angular
>   replaces the `<ng-template>` and its contents with a comment.

[Source](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives)

As soon as you use the template somewhere like e.g.:

```
<ng-content *ngTemplateOutlet="first"></ng-content>
```

you will also be able to access it's content via a Viewchild.